# Rails Includes Error : UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I prefer use includes to connect my three tables. I have three model that I need to connect such as Register, Student, and Schedule. Here is my model Association

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :register
end

class Register < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :student

    belongs_to :schedule
end

class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :teacher

    has_many :days, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'ScheduleDay'
    has_many :registers
end
```

Here is my controller

```
def index
        @students = Student.includes([register: :schedule])
        @students = @students.order 'students.created_at DESC'


        if params[:status_id] && params[:status_id].to_i > 0
            @students = @students.where 'students.status_id = ?', params[:status_id]
        end

        if params[:id] && params[:id].to_i > 0
            @students = @students.where 'cast(students.id as varchar) like (?)', "%#{params[:id]}%"
        end

        if params[:full_name] && params[:full_name].to_s.length > 0
            @students = @students.where 'lower(registers.name_in_indonesian || registers.name_in_chinese) like lower(?)', "%#{params[:full_name]}%"
        end

        if params[:course_id] && params[:course_id].to_i > 0
            @students = @students.where 'schedules.course_id = ?', params[:course_id]
        end

        @students = @students.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
end
```

I got following error :

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "schedules"
LINE 1: SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE (schedules.course_...
```

I tried to debug by using rails console but end up with **(Object doesn't support #inspect)**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [join](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) those tables if you want to query them, [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) is not enough:

```
@students = Student.joins(register: :schedule)
```

or add a [`references`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) call:

```
@students = Student.includes(register: :schedule).references(register: :schedule)
```

`includes` will reduce the number of database queries to access the included tables but it won't JOIN the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some unmigrated migrations. Please run

> rake db:migrate

After running above command restart rails console and then try the same thing. You will not be getting this error.

Comment: All my migrations has been migrated

Comment: Ok actually same thing happened with me so at that time I was having unmigrated migrations.

Comment: You can proof it from my screenshoot, when i tried to call Student.includes register: :schedule